# How would you get an auto_increment value on an insert query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So, I was wondering if you were to launch this query:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, gender, location) VALUES ('Ricky-Bobby', 'm', 'Daytona Beach, FL');
```

And suppose that `users` has another auto-incrementing columns for the primary key, how would you be able to get the value of that primary key without launching another query?

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter simplifies the MySQL query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` through the function `$this->db->insert_id()`.

Although this *is* a query, it's a very light one that won't be a performance issue. One thing to have in note is this:

- If you want the ID on the row you inserted; `$this->db->insert_id()`
- If you want the auto_increment value, that is the next value that an `INSERT` will have as `id`, simply `$this->db->insert_id() + 1`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the second option due to concurrency issues. IMO you should only recover after inserting. (If the ops aren't very close, even the first option may fail)

Comment: I agree. The only time I've assumed IDs before they are created are when I built a database from scratch and only run the query once. I've yet to have a good reason to do anything else than fetching the ID after insertion.

Answer (score 3):

codeigniter makes this available with `$this->db->last_insert_id()`

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: Your an also fetch it directly from MySQL by executing this statement: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM users`.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) with your query:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, gender, location) VALUES ('Ricky-Bobby', 'm', 'Daytona Beach, FL');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if you are using PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php